# how to get value from firebase as date while using moment.js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, momentjs

I'm using firebase as database and momentjs for dates on my Ionic Project.

I save needed dates on firebase but i want to take 2 dates and find difference between them as hours, days etc.

But when i try to take this value's something goes wrong and can not take difference.

Fields on firebase.

[image]

My code.

```
let ms = moment(this.userActivityLoginTime,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss")
  .diff(moment(this.userActivityLogoutTime,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));

let d = moment.duration(ms);

console.log(d.days(), d.hours(), d.minutes(), d.seconds());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong. You are trying to subtract bigger value from smaller one. Try code below.

```
  let ms = moment(this.userActivityLogoutTime,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(this.userActivityLoginTime,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));

  let d = moment.duration(ms);

  console.log(d.months(),d.days(), d.hours(), d.minutes(), d.seconds());
```

Comment: that does not wrong. response is still `NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN`.

Comment: Have a look at the plunkr I created. It works.. https://plnkr.co/edit/xunuJk?p=preview

Comment: Also Please add console.log after each statement of your code in case you still have trouble in order to make sure that your code is returning proper results after each line

Comment: Yes. If i define the dates on .ts it works i know. But i try to get them from database and it does not work.

Comment: How are you accessing the firebase instance?

Comment: You can have a look at firebase documentation or try angularFire2 to serve your purpose . there is nothing wrong in the code . It is a possibility that you are not able to access those value from firebase in correct manner

Comment: `this.userActivityData = this.firebaseProvider.getUserActivity();
    
    this.userActivityData.subscribe(data => {
      this.userActivityLoginTime = data.lastLogInOtopark;
      this.userActivityLogoutTime = data.lastLogOutOtopark;
    });`

Comment: I can the values correctly. But probably moment.js can not take these as Date. I can not solve that.

Comment: you should be wrting the moment logic inside your subscribe. Is that not the case?

Comment: What you you mean?

Comment: `this.userActivityData = this.firebaseProvider.getUserActivity(); this.userActivityData.subscribe(data => { this.userActivityLoginTime = data.lastLogInOtopark; this.userActivityLogoutTime = data.lastLogOutOtopark;   let ms = moment(this.userActivityLogoutTime,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(this.userActivityLoginTime,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));

  let d = moment.duration(ms);

  console.log(d.months(),d.days(), d.hours(), d.minutes(), d.seconds());  });`

Comment: The issue is not in the moment. Check what value you are getting in data. Do a console.log below line this.userActivityLoginTime = data.lastLogInOtopark; in your function. You can try creating a pluker for what you have tried. I"ll have a look on the plunkr.

Comment: Yes, you right. I was trying to get datas in constructor and because of that it goes wrong. :) Thanks.